# How to use after_idle to insert a value without stopping validation?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

After reading through the [tkinter documentation on validation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7) to try and find a solution to the validation stopping when I inserted a value into my entry widget, I found it included the command `after idle {%W config -validate %v}`.

I thought this might prove to help me with my problem, but I have no real idea how to implement it into a code and I don't really understand the `%W config -validate %v` part of it, could someone please help explain it to me?

Comment: I would also like someone to explain [after idle {%W config -validate %v} ] from Tk docs.